# What is the purpose of userError and isUserError functions?

Tags: haskell

I'm exploring the exception mechanism in Haskell. I have figured out how `catch` and `handler` functions work.

```
main = toTry `catch` handler

handler :: IOError -> IO ()  
handler e  
    | isDoesNotExistError e = putStrLn "The file doesn't exist!"  
    | otherwise = ioError e
```

The type of `userError` is `String -> IOError`. As I understand, that means we can pass `userError` as `e` in the aforementioned `handler`. Hoogle says about `userError` "Construct an `IOError` value with a string describing the error." But how to actually construct `userError` and what is the purpose of it? `userError` takes only a `String`, how can it possibly do anything?

For example, the aforementioned `isDoesNotExistError e` has its like own internal logic (as I understand), which deals with "does not exist" case. But we construct our own `userError :: String -> IOError` using only a `String`, so after all, is `userError` kind of a synonym for our `String`?

I would be grateful if you showed a simple example of using `userError` and `isUserError`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`userError` is basically a smart constructor for a value of type `IOError` (which itself is an alias for `IOException`), which uses a single data constructor also named `IOError`. Two of the fields are `ice_type :: IOErrorType` and `ioe_description :: String`; the rest of the fields aren't relevant to `UserError`, so `userError` is really just a wrapper around the data constructor `IOError`:

```
userError       :: String  -> IOError
userError str   =  IOError Nothing UserError "" str Nothing Nothing
```

When you want to raise your own `IOError`, you use `userError` to create it; the resulting `IOError` value is what gets passed to the handler.

`isUserError e` simply tests if `ioe_type e` is `UserError`.